# Behavior of D and Derivative when acting on functions with Rules as arguments

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, built-in-symbols

I was (pleasantly) surprised that when a `D`erivative is taken of a symbolic function for which the last few arguments are `Rule`s, a `Derivative` object is returned with just the right number of arguments to ignore the `Rule`s:

```
D[f[x,y,a->b],x] // InputForm
(*  Derivative[0,1][f][x,y,a->b]  *)

(*  NOT:  Derivative[0,1,0][f][x,y,a->b] *)
```

This makes sense since the `Rule`s could represents options to the function `f`.

**Question**: Has this behavior of `D` and `Derivative` been with *Mathematica* since v1?

But, then there is a strange behavior when `D` is taken of a function in which a `Rule` appears in a middle argument:

```
D[f[x,a->b,y],x]
(*  (0 -> 0) Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, a -> b, y] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, a -> b, y] *)

D[f[x,a->b,y],y]
(*  Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, a -> b, y] + (0 -> 0)*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, a -> b, y] *)
```

**Question**:  what is the interpretation of this output?  In particular, what is the meaning of the term proportional to `0 -> 0`?

Comment: It looks like `D` threads over `Rule`: e.g. `D[x -> x, x]` evaluates to `1 -> 1`. So it looks like the behavior you're seeing is a chain rule: for some reason `D` sees the `Rule` as a function of `x`, and so applies the chain rule. The `D` then threads over `a -> b`, yielding `0 -> 0` since `a` and `b` are independent of `x`.

Comment: @march I would report that, don't you think?

Comment: @Kuba I forgot about this! I will do this later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `D` `Thread`s over `Rule`:

```
D[x -> x, x]
(* 1 -> 1 *)
```

Thus, the behavior you're seeing is just the chain rule. `D` sees `f[x, Rule[a, b], y]` as a function of three inputs, and so takes the derivative of the outside function multiplied by the inside functions:

```
D[f[x, a -> b, y], x]
(* (0 -> 0) Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, a -> b, y] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, a -> b, y] *)
```

Interestingly, there's something special about the way that `D` treats functions with `Rule`s as arguments. Aside from the observation made in the OP (that `D` sees `f[x, a -> b]` as a function of *one* argument `x`, with the second argument understood to be `Options` for `f`), there is also the following. Even if I try to `UpSet` automatic `Thread`ing for `D` of some undefined symbol `g`,

```
g /: D[g[a_, b_], x_] := g[D[a, x], D[b, x]]
SetAttributes[g, SequenceHold]  (* to mimic the `Attributes` of `Rule` *)
```

the behavior noted in the OP doesn't occur:

```
D[f[x, g[a, b], y], x]
(* Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, a -> b, y] *)
```

which means that `D` looks at the structure of the expression as a whole first and decides what arguments are functions of `x` and which are not *before* applying derivatives to those arguments according to the chain rule. Of course, it does this *unless* one of the arguments is a `Rule`, in which case it *does* take the derivative of the argument (or it `Thread`s over it, depending on where it is in the expression).

This is not a complete answer, since I don't know why (and exactly how) `D` treats `Rule`s as arguments separately. Nonetheless, the OP *is* seeing a chain rule, so that's the explanation for the behavior in the OP.